# Como solucionar error con java.reflect y creacion de bean en spring boot java

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection, cqrs

primero voy a dar un poco de contexto antes de mostrar el error. Estoy con una API Rest con Spring Boot (spring boot 2.6.6 y Java 17), en la cual me empezó a salir el siguiente error al intentar ejecutar.
La cola de error completa

```
Error creating bean with name 'deleteAccountResource' defined in file [C:\ruta...\resources\DeleteAccountResource.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springCommandBus' defined in file [C:\ruta...\SpringCommandBus.class]: Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [dev.facturador.global.infrastructure.adapters.SpringCommandBus]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Lo que quiero solucionar es:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Class cannot be cast to class java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType (java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

Del error entiendo que el problema esta en la clase SpringCommandBuss o en la clase DeleteAccountResource. Primero SpringCommandBuss esta es una clase sirve como servicio para que funcione mi arquitectura, se encarga de elegir el commandHandler a ejecutar según el comando que le pases. DeleteAccountResource, por otro lado esta clase es un endPoint (se encarga literalmente de lo que dice el nombre de la clase)

Ahora muestro los componentes que forman parte de la implementacion de un command

```java
//El comando es el encargado de transportar los datos (esta es una implementacion abstracta)
public class Command {
}

//El handler recibe el comando sin saber cual es y ejecuta la accion
@FunctionalInterface
public interface CommandHandler<T extends Command> {
    void handle(T command) throws Exception;
}
```

Ahora la clase SpringCommandBuss

```
@Service
@Primary
public class SpringCommandBus implements CommandBus {
    private final Map<Class, CommandHandler> handlers;

    /**Se encarga de buscar todos los comandos*/
    public SpringCommandBus(List<CommandHandler> commandHandlerImplementations) {
        this.handlers = new HashMap<>();
        commandHandlerImplementations.forEach(commandHandler -> {
            //Aqui esta el error
            Class<?> commandClass = getCommandClass(commandHandler);
            handlers.put(commandClass, commandHandler);
        });
    }
    /**Busca un handler para el comando y ejecuta este si lo encuentra*/
    @Override
    public void handle(Command command) throws Exception {
        //Si no existe un Handler con este comando da error
        if (!handlers.containsKey(command.getClass())) {
            throw new Exception(String.format("No handler for %s", command.getClass().getName()));
        }
        //Si no dio error entonces solo busca la implementacion y ejecuta su metodo handle
        handlers.get(command.getClass()).handle(command);
    }

    /**Busca la clase de la implementacion utilizando la libreria de {@link java.lang.reflect}*/
    public Class<?> getCommandClass(CommandHandler handler) {
        Type commandInterface = ((ParameterizedType) handler.getClass()
                .getGenericInterfaces()[0]).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
          //Aqui es donde sale el error
        return getClass(commandInterface.getTypeName());
    }

    /**Una vez recupera el nombre del tipo del handler recupera la clase de esta*/
    public Class<?> getClass(String name) {
        try {
            return Class.forName(name);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

En el endpoint DeleteAccountResource es llamado de esta forma:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/accounts")
public class DeleteAccountResource {
    private final CommandBus commandBus;

    public DeleteAccountResource(CommandBus commandBus) {
        this.commandBus = commandBus;
    }

    /**
     * @param username Nombre de usuario de la cuenta que se quiere eliminar
     * @return RespomseEmtity vació con el código 204
     */
    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @DeleteMapping("/{username}")
    public HttpEntity<Void> deleteAccount(@PathVariable @NotEmpty String username) throws Exception {

        var command = AccountDeleteCommand.Builder.getInstance()
                .username(username).build();

        commandBus.handle(command);
        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }
}
```

A modo de aportar mas información agrego también la implementación del handler

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
@Transactional
public class AccountDeleteCommandHandler implements CommandHandler<AccountDeleteCommand> {
    private final ChecksAccountService checkUseCase;
    private final AccountRepository repository;

    /**
     * Maneja la eliminacion de una cuenta de usuario
     *
     * @param command Comando contiene los datos para eliminar una cuenta de usuario
     * @throws Exception
     */
    @Override
    public void handle(AccountDeleteCommand command) throws Exception {
        //Comprueba que exista esta cuenta antes de eliminar
        if (!checkUseCase.checkAccountExistsByUsername(command.getUsername())) {
            throw new ResourceNotFound("No existe una cuenta con este username");
        }

        repository.deleteByOwnerUserUsername(command.getUsername());
    }
}
```

Como dato command forma parte de mi forma de implentar el patron CQS(Command Query Separation).
Si se le ocurre una forma de arreglar el error o mejorar mi implementacion (y esta mejora solucione el error) lo agradeceria. Puede ser que se me este escapando algo y el error este en otro sitio por agregue la cola de error completa.

Comment: y tu modulo como lo definiste?

Comment: @RuslanLópez A que te referís con modulo?

Comment: por supuesto al JPMS, del cual proviene el mensaje de error `java.lang.Class and java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType are in module java.base `

Comment: @RuslanLópez Hasta donde se no lo defino yo, debería estar por default. Edite la pregunte para marcar donde la consola dice que esta el error

Comment: suponiendo que sea cierto checa: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23074446/java-lang-classcastexception-java-lang-class-cannot-be-cast-to-java-lang-reflec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final no encontré exactamente cual era el problema, pero analizando lo que necesitaba note que podía solucionar mi problema utilizando otros métodos, asi que refactorizando un poco el código me funciono de esta forma:

```java
//El atributo lo deje asi
private final Map<Class<? extends Command>, CommandHandler> handlers;

//Cambiando este metodo se soluciono todo.
public Class<? extends Command> getCommandClass(CommandHandler handler) {
        var methods = Arrays.stream(handler.getClass().getMethods()).toList()
                .stream()
                .filter(x -> x.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("handle"))
                .filter(x -> !x.getParameterTypes()[0].getSimpleName().startsWith("Command"))
                .toList();
        return (Class<? extends Command>) getClass(methods
                .get(0).getParameterTypes()[0].getCanonicalName());
}
```